# Are there reputation change events that don't show on the reputation page?

Tags: support, reputation

I thought with the recent changes to the reputation system you'd see every adjustment, including post or user deletions, in the reputation page. Are there still exceptions? I'm quite sure I saw my reputation drop by 95 points when I refreshed the page this morning, and that included a +15 that was recorded properly.

Edit: I was able to verify the drop at a second PC. I also didn't know about the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of the reputation page, but checking that box didn't change the results.

**Edit 2:** I really don't care about the points themselves, I earned them all back within a day and I presume there was a good reason for them to disappear. Thus I've changed the title to the question, because I'm still curious to know what happened.

Comment: You have to check that box at the bottom of the "Reputation" tab to see information about removed posts.  Did you do that yet?  (This was added when the rep changes happened, so I figured you might not have heard of it yet)

Comment: @jadarnel27, You're right I didn't know about the checkbox. But checking it didn't make any difference.

Comment: The checkbox works for me...

Comment: @Manishearth, it probably works for me too, which means the drop didn't come from a removed post.

Comment: @MarkRansom: To get rid of the "probably", find your most downvoted post, delete it, check if the checkbox works, and undelete it. (You may have to wait a bit for the cache to refresh) Checking this is imperative to identify where the bug comes from.

Comment: @Manishearth I seriously doubt that the problem is the "show removed posts" functionality only not working for him.

Comment: @jadarnel27: Yep, but its always a good idea to narrow down stuff while debugging. Otherwise you get those facepalm moments after hours of debugging and realize that you're on the wrong track.. Makes the devs jobs easier :)

Comment: @Manishearth, I found a bad answer with -1 votes and deleted it - indeed I got back 2 points and it only shows up when I have the box checked. I'm not going to bother to undelete it.

Comment: I noticed after checking the box I had to wait a short time or flip between reputation views before the deleted posts finally showed up in my reputation history.  It was a little disconcerting at first.

Comment: @Troyen, I put the checkmark in the box hours ago, and I still don't have any evidence of where the points went.

Comment: Hrm. I can see *how* your lost rep, but not *why*. I pinged a dev to look into this further.