# Are there reputation changes that do not appear on a user's reputation tab?

Tags: bug, reputation, privileges

I ask this question from the context of having received notifications of 3 earned privileges for a low reputation account where the account reputation total was <10 points below the threshold for these privileges and nothing in the reputation tab history or related to any logged activity on questions and answers could account for the acquisition or reversal of reputation gained. I have since passed the threshold reputation score, so the issue no longer applies. I offer this feedback as a potential bug or to promote greater understanding.

[image: Notifications]   [image: Reputation]

After having tried suggestions in this [related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127976/are-there-reputation-change-events-that-dont-show-on-the-reputation-page) and having researched questions related to privilege notifications and automated (script) detection and management of serial upvoting and downvoting, there does not appear to be an answer to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone votes and then cancels that vote fairly quickly i.e. before it locks in, or accepts and then unaccepts an answer on the same day then that can trigger the notification message without any visible rep change.

If the post is edited after the initial upvote then that would cancel the vote lock and the unupvote could then take place at any time on that same day. You'd see one of your posts had been edited so there would be some circumstantial evidence this might have happened.

Animuson provided some of the information in this post via a comment.

Comment: Thank you. The scenario that you describe, as the possibility of some sort of race condition, had occurred to me. I appreciate the confirmation.

Comment: It doesn't have to be fairly quickly. If a users upvotes and unupvotes or accepts and unaccepts a post on the same day, both the events are hidden from the reputation history to prevent clutter. An event could disappear for up to 24 hours, depending on when it was created during the day.